# matplotlib plot for probabilities

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

What is an adequate plot type for probabilities?
For example if I have the following data:

```
t p1 p2 p3 p4
1 0 0 0 1
2 0.1 0 0 0.9
3 0.2 0 0 0.8
4 0.2 0.3 0 0.5
```

You can see that the values (other than t) sum 1.

I seem to remember there is some kind of bar graph that sum 1 but with the divisions of different colors.

Something like
[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas` to load the data and then create the following plot with `matplotlib`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=0)

samples = df.index.astype(str)
bottom = np.zeros(len(df))
width = 0.5

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xlabel='Samples', ylabel='Probability')
for label, probabilities in df.transpose().iterrows():
    ax.bar(samples, probabilities, width, bottom=bottom, label=label)
    bottom += probabilities
ax.legend(title='Classes')
plt.show()
```

[image: Example plot]

Comment: Thanks! What is the name of this type of graph?

Comment: It's called bar graph

Comment: @KansaiRobot As the name of the method indicates, it's called [bar chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_chart).